# PowerShell to exe

Tags: powershell

Invoke-PS2EXE C:\Users\naimur\Downloads\apps.ps1 C:\Users\naimur\Downloads\apps.exe
Invoke-PS2EXE : The 'Invoke-PS2EXE' command was found in the module 'ps2exe', but the module could not be loaded. For
more information, run 'Import-Module ps2exe'.
At line:1 char:1

- Invoke-PS2EXE C:\Users\naimur\Downloads\apps.ps1 C:\Users\naimur\Down ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Invoke-PS2EXE:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoloadMatchingModule
  ```

help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.